# How can I keep the space in text transferred to new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, firefox

When user clicks on "next" button, the data from two separate text boxes is transferred to the new page but there are %20 in place of where spaces should be.  How can I avoid that?

Inline javascript from originalpage.html

```
$('#next').click(function(){
        var coachFullName = $('#coach_txt_box').val();
        var teamName = $('#team_txt_box').val();
        if(!!coachFullName){
window.location.href = 'newpage.html?zip=' + coachFullName + teamName;
        } else {
            $('# coach_txt_box').watermark('please enter coach name',{className: 'watermarkError'});
        }
    });
```

Inline javascript from newpage.html

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    if(results == null)
        return "";
    else
        document.signupform.coach_and_team_name.value = results[1];
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

getParameterByName('coach');
```

Comment: the prolbem of %20 appearing only happens in Firefox. In IE it looks okay.

Comment: By which method you get this transferred text in the New page...?

Comment: @JohnMontague i think this is done automatically by the browser since spaces aren't allowed in URI's. There may be differences between browsers and builds ...

Answer (score -1):

you should use some thing like 
[`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) in php or [`decodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) ..

there is no need for regex to accomplish what you want